# Variable in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Can I use variable in start_urls? Please see script below:

This script work fine:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from example.items import ExampleItem

class ExampleSpider(Spider):
name = "example"
allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
start_urls = [

"http://www.example.com/search-keywords=['0750692995']",
"http://www.example.com/search-keywords=['0205343929']",
"http://www.example.com/search-keywords=['0874367379']",

]

def parse(self, response):
   hxs = Selector(response)
   item = ExampleItem()
   item['url'] = response.url
   item['price'] = hxs.select("//li[@class='mpbold']/a/text()").extract()
   item['title'] = hxs.select("//span[@class='title L']/text()").extract()
   return item
```

But I want like this:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from example.items import ExampleItem

class ExampleSpider(Spider):
name = "example"
allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
pro_id = ["0750692995", "0205343929", "0874367379"] ***(I added this line)
start_urls = [

"http://www.example.com/search-keywords=['pro_id']", ***(and I changed this line)

]

def parse(self, response):
   hxs = Selector(response)
   item = ExampleItem()
   item['url'] = response.url
   item['price'] = hxs.select("//li[@class='mpbold']/a/text()").extract()
   item['title'] = hxs.select("//span[@class='title L']/text()").extract()
   return item
```

I would like to run this script by pull the pro_id number into start_urls function one by one. Is there any way to do that? I run the script but the URL still like this "http://www.example.com/search-keywords=['pro_id']" not "http://www.example.com/search-keywords=0750692995". How the script should be? Thank you for your help.

EDIT: after making @paul t's suggested change, the following error occurs

```
2014-03-02 08:39:44+0700 [example] ERROR: Obtaining request from start requests
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1192, in run
        self.mainLoop()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1201, in mainLoop
        self.runUntilCurrent()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 824, in runUntilCurrent
        call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.22.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\utils\reactor.py", line 41, in __call__
        return self._func(*self._a, **self._kw)
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.22.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 111, in _next_request

        request = next(slot.start_requests)
      File "C:\Users\S\desktop\example\example\spiders\example_spider.py", line 13, in start_requests
        yield Request(self.start_urls_base % pro_id, dont_filter=True)
    exceptions.NameError: global name 'Request' is not defined
```

Comment: Add `from scrapy.http.request import Request` to resolve the error that occurs after making @paul t.'s suggested change.

Answer (score 5):

One way yo do that is to override the spider's `start_requests()` method:

```
class ExampleSpider(Spider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    pro_ids = ["0750692995", "0205343929", "0874367379"]
    start_urls_base = "http://www.example.com/search-keywords=['%s']"

    def start_requests(self):
        for pro_id in self.pro_ids:
            yield Request(self.start_urls_base % pro_id, dont_filter=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to import Request

```
from scrapy.http import Request
```

after this you can follow suggestion by Paul

```
    def start_requests(self):
    for pro_id in self.pro_ids:
        yield Request(self.start_urls_base % pro_id, dont_filter=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use a for loop solve it ,like following:

```
start_urls = [

"http://www.example.com/search-keywords="+i for i in pro_id

]
```